# Creating StatefulSet cluster across regions

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, replicaset, kubernetes-statefulset

Is it possible with K8s to create the stateful replica set across region,i want to have the MongoDB replica set across various regions, suppose i wanted to create the 3 memeber mongoDB replica set:

Member 1: us-east

Member 2: eu-west

Member 3: ca-central

Will it be possible with kubernetes statefulsets and Headless Service?

Comment: which cloud are you on ?

Comment: @tarunkhosla AWS

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/multiple-zones/ 
You can set up in multiple zones but you cannot have them in US , Europe and CA

Comment: yes have gone through that, is there any OOTB way to this if possible?

Comment: if your cluster is set up across regions you can deploy across availability zones.

Comment: Does my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147804/creating-statefulset-cluster-across-regions) solves your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can setup a statefulset object across regions. Instead you can deploy across availability zones. Create a kubernetes cluster with three node pools one each in different availability zone. You can distribute the mongodb statefulset across the three nodepools.

If your requirement is to have the mongodb cluster across region then consider separate mongodb cluster in each region and then have a mechanism to replicate the data between the two clusters.

Comment: is there any way of replicating the data across the multiple cluster of mongodb